# a twitter-like signup form

Tags: html, css, forms

can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial that would get me similar functionality of twitter's signup form on their homepage?

specifically I'm referring to having the 'name' and 'password' etc. text fade when selected and disappear when you start typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll need some Javascript to perform the fadeout animation based on a focus event when the user starts to fill out the form.  Here's a good tutorial and demo to get you started:

http://www.webstuffshare.com/2010/03/mask-your-input-forms-and-make-it-beauty/

http://webstuffshare.com/demo/InputShadow/

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem.  Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

to having the 'name' and 'password' etc. text disappear

placeholder Attribute

The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field (e.g. a sample value or a short description of the expected format).

The hint is displayed in the input field when it is empty, and disappears when the field gets focus.